# A function inside a function constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this code:

```
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
}

Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v){
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }
};
```

Is it possible to add the `addVertex` property name inside `function Graph()` and thus eliminate the second part of this code altogether (from where `Graph.prototype =` begins)? I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
  addVertex = function(v){
    this.vertices.push(v);
  };
}
```

Comment: It would be `this.addVertex = function...`

Comment: Gauvar Sacnchan's answer is correct but if you wan't to attach the function to the prototype of the object you should change this.addVertex with Graph.prototype.addVertex

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in the following manner:

```
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
  this.addVertex = function(v){
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }; 
 return this;
}
```